# JavaScript Safari/FireFox browser height

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, safari

I have this JavaScript code and it does not work in FireFox or Safari with transitional:

```
var htmlheight = myHeight;
if (myHeight > 0) {
    var viewer = document.getElementById("<%= rvControl.ClientID %>");
    viewer.style.height = htmlheight - 2 + 'px';
}
```

It does not appear to work in IE also, so I am a bit dumbfounded!

Can someone tell me how I can change the height of my `div` in Safari and FireFox?

Comment: is myHeight html.height or body.height?

Comment: Body Hight, just curious, why does that matter?

Comment: sometimes, html and body doesn't have height in transitional. can you try adding `html,body{height:100%;}` at the beginning of your css? i can't remember the exact details of why, or i'd post it as an aswer

Comment: also, some html would be useful. try creating a jsFiddle that shows the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    viewer.style.height = (htmlheight - 2) + 'px'
```

Comment: that does not work either, actually I just added the - 2 right before this post.  I needed that because I added a border to my div and need to remove two pixels.  So, I did try it without the -2 and i just tried it with the parens for grins and still no luck.

Comment: That is very peculiar. Is the `display` property set to `block`? I'm pretty sure Transitional isn't weird about setting a height property.

Answer (score 0):

From the sound of it, your `viewer` is an inline element - you cannot set a height on these, it will be ignored (at least in a standards-compliant browser). You should specify either `display: block` or `display: inline-block` style on it, depending on your layout.

Comment: Ok, I added viewer.style.display = 'block'; and that seemed to fix it in IE, but not Safari or FireFox which are two browsers i need to support.  Any other suggestions?